# Timestamp at which a contact is created

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, abaddressbooksource

Is there any way to get the timestamp when the contact is created/added . I want to sort contact list time wise in which order they are stored

Answer (score 0):

You have creation date property of contacts

```
NSArray *allPeople = ((__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addresbook));

for (int i = 0; i < allPeople.count; i++) {
    ABRecordRef *person = (ABAddressBookRef *)[allPeople objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDate *creationDate = ((__bridge_transfer NSDate*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonCreationDateProperty));
    NSLog(@"Creation date: %@ of entry: %@", creationDate, person);
}
```

Comment: but what will happen to old number already stores in addressbook

Comment: What do you mean? which old number? who stores the old number?

Comment: I want the timestamp of all numbers which were stored in my iphone
So that I can sort the numbers according to time at which I saved them.

Comment: You have only creation date and last modification date of contacts and not numbers. I do not think iOS saves dates for every number. It means you can sort the contacts but not the numbers.